# repo init warning: failed to restrict file handles

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

Here when I run `repo init -u git@foo.bar -b dev` on windows , and it shows a warning `repo init warning: failed to restrict file handles`, seems like some files get broken, any one could do me a favor ? thanks all the time : )

Answer (score 0):

Install previous version of git [v2.15.1.windows.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.15.1.windows.2)